# VSC debugging Node.js Typescript running on WSL

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to debug Node.js app written with Typescript, running on WSL.

Environment is:

- OS: Windows 10
- Debug tool: VSC 1.24.1 / VSC 1.25 / VSC 1.26.0
- WSL: Ubuntu 18.04
- Application: Typescript Node.js, codes from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

My launch.json is:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [        

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script",
            "debug"
        ],
        "port": 9229,
        "useWSL": true,
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "timeout": 100000,
        "restart": true,
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
]
```

}

When I press F5, it does not stop at Debug breakpoints and saying "benerated code not found".
But when I look at dist folder, it has *.map files.

Could you please help me to figure it out?

And is there any way to remote-debug the Typescript node.js app running on WSL?
I could not find the solution.

Thanks in advance!

**--Update--**

**VSC 1.25 has a bug regarding remote debug, please try 1.24.1 or 1.26**

Instead I found how to attach it and debugger works.  launch.json needs the below:

```
        {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach WSL",
        "port": 9229,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "/mnt/c/prj/tmp/TypeScript-Node-Starter",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
        ]
    },
```

To test, set break point at home.ts:8, and load "localhost:3000" from your brower.

It might miss it at first try (I know it sounds weird), but reload once again.
When you set a breakpoint, it might complain saying "unverified ..." or "not yet bound".  However when codes run, it will be verified.

Happy debugging life!

Comment: This may help https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ch9Live/Windows-Community-Standup/Kevin-Gallo-April-2018

Comment: @BiswapriyoThanks for reply.  I checked it but it does not help for TS.  I've tried the following link as well: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/27/running-node-js-on-wsl-from-visual-studio-code/